# Relation between $P(X>x,Y<y)$ and $P(X<x,Y<y)$

Tags: probability

Is there a simple relation between $P(X>x,Y<y)$ and $P(X<x,Y<y)$. Just like $P(Z<z)=1-P(Z>z)$.

Comment: What exactly are you asking?

Comment: If one can be expressed in terms of the other?

Comment: what are $X$ and $Y$? Discrete random variables? Continuous random variables?

Comment: Remember that the comma in $P(A,B)$ is an intersection or "and". The two events whose probabilities you want to relate are disjoint. What is their union?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $a=\mathbb P(X>x,Y<y)$ and $b=\mathbb P(X<x,Y<y)$. Since the events $A:=\{X>x\}\cap \{Y<y\}$ and $B:=\{X<x\}\cap \{Y<y\}$ are disjoint and $A\cup B=\{X\neq x\}\cap\{Y<y\}$, it follows that
$$
a+b=\mathbb P(X\neq x,Y<y).
$$
In  particular, if $\mathbb P(X=x)=0$, we get the simpler expression
$$
a+b=\mathbb P(Y<y).
$$